# Store custom error handling messages in a session

Tags: php, error-handling

If mode is production than I don't want show any fatal error or warning etc to user. What I want to achieve is to check if any kind of error occurs, to store the data in a in session array, than redirect to some custom page.

**Problem**

After redirect to other page the session array which store all the error show empty?

**Mode production**

Than execute the error_handler function

```
 if($GLOBAL['MODE'] == 'PROD'){
   ini_set('log_errors',FALSE);
  set_error_handler("errorHandler");

 }
```

**Code**

```
ini_get(0);

//Declare session array
$_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = array();

register_shutdown_function("shutdownHandler");

function errorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, 
$error_line, $error_context)
{

 $error = " Msg:" . $error_message . " file:" . $error_file . " ln:" . 
 $error_line;

 switch ($error_level) {
 case E_ERROR:
 case E_CORE_ERROR:
 case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
 case E_PARSE:

  $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error;
  mylog($error, "fatal");
  break;
  case E_USER_ERROR:
  case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:

  $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error;

  mylog($error, "error");
  break;
  case E_WARNING:
  case E_CORE_WARNING:
  case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
  case E_USER_WARNING:

  //Store all errors in session array    <<<<---------

  $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error; 
  mylog($error, "warn");

   break;
   case E_NOTICE:
   case E_USER_NOTICE:
   $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error;
   $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error; 
   mylog($error, "info");
   break;
   case E_STRICT:
   $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error; 
    mylog($error, "debug");
   break;
   default:
   $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error; 
   mylog($error, "warn");

  }
}

 function shutdownHandler() //will be called when php script ends.
 {
  $lasterror = error_get_last();
  switch ($lasterror['type'])
  {
    case E_ERROR:
    case E_CORE_ERROR:
    case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
    case E_USER_ERROR:
    case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
    case E_CORE_WARNING:
    case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
    case E_PARSE:
    $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = $error; 
    $error = "[SHUTDOWN] lvl:" . $lasterror['type'] . " | msg:" . 
    $lasterror['message'] . " | file:" . $lasterror['file'] . " | ln:" . 
     $lasterror['line'];
    mylog($error, "fatal");
    }
  }

function mylog($error, $errlvl)
{
  if($error){
   //redirect to custom-page 
    }
}
```

**Custom-page**

```
print_r($_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR']);  //Problem its show empty
die;
```

**For a better understanding the problem I want to achieve this simply**

```
 $_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'] = set_error_handler("errorHandler");
 if(!empty($_SESSION['CUSTOM_ERROR'])){
   //redirect
 }
```

Comment: Use this row at the top of each webpage:

if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

Comment: Its not work...

Comment: @Adam1 Where did you put it ? It should be in both files: (1) http://prntscr.com/n3zvia and (2) http://prntscr.com/n3zvom

Comment: I put it at the top my file which is include in every page.